# cannot access javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader while using JacksonJsonProvider.setMapper

Tags: spring, jackson, jersey, glassfish, fasterxml

Im facing cannot access javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader while upgrading to spring 6.
Im using glassfish jersey 3.1.0 for REST services in spring 6 application and com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider 2.14.1.

Im facing this compilation error while calling JacksonJsonProvider.setMapper()

i cant able to figure out how to solve this issue.

Comment: Spring 6/Jersey 3 are using Jakarta EE APIs, i.e. `jakarta.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader`. You are mixing old and new dependencies.

Comment: @jan.supol so what should i need to do to solve it

Comment: Check the dependencies in Jersey 3 for [Jackson](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/3.1/media/json-jackson/pom.xml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved this issue by replacing

```
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
```

with

```
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider</artifactId>
```

Comment: do you mind to add detail to your response? where did you replaced that?

Comment: Thank you for sharing both the question and the answer. I just spent the whole day on this, after upgrading from jersey 2.something to 3.1.1.
You saved me a lot of time.
I would only add, that import statements have to be updated, ex:
    //import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.annotation.JacksonFeatures;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs.annotation.JacksonFeatures;